# Data year wise sql

Tags: sql-server, count

I try to get data year wise. I tried this query

```
select 
    year(SStartDate) as joinedyear ,
    count(*) joined_total 
from 
    Detail
where 
    client = 81 
Group By 
    YEAR(StartDate)

union all 

select 
    year(SEndDate) as leftyear,  
    count(*) left_total 
from 
    Detail
where 
    client = 81 
Group By 
    YEAR(SEndDate)
```

This shows correct data but this shows data like this

```
1900  12
2001  1
2012  3
2013 3 
2016  45
1900  23
2002  34
2004 34
2015  1
2016 56
```

where as I want data like this

```
joinedyear  joined_total leftyear left_total

1900           12         1900      45
2001           1          2002      34     
2012           3         2004       34
2013           3         2015       1    
2016          45         2016     56
```

Comment: Istead of using union all. try using joining tables using inner join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This below query..it mat help you

```
      select * from (
    select year(SStartDate) as joinedyear ,
    count(*) joined_total from Detail
    where client=81 
    Group By YEAR(StartDate)
    ) as a
    full outer join 
    (
    select year(SEndDate) as leftyear , count(*) left_total from Detail
    where client=81 
    Group By YEAR(SEndDate)
    ) as b
    on a.joinedyear=b.leftyear
```